# Regresar el preview de una imagen para actualizar los datos MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy trabajando con MVC y ya logré guardar la imagen en una url, la imagen se guarda de la forma "Assets/img/nombreimg.jpg", de esa forma se guarda en mi base de datos.

Este es mi controlador:

```
 public JsonResult Agregar()
        {
            try
            {
                var cNombre = Request.Form["cNombre"];
                var cClave = Request.Form["cClave"];
                var cHashtag = Request.Form["cHashtag"];
                var cColor = Request.Form["cColor"];
                var archi = Request.Files["FileUpload"];

                bool ProcesoGuardado = true;
                string ImageName = "";
                string json = "";

                TipoRecursoDTO oTipoRecurso = new TipoRecursoDTO();

                foreach (string filename in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[filename];

                    ImageName = file.FileName;

                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/img/TipoRecursos"));
                        string pathstring = Path.Combine(path.ToString());
                        var filename1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                        bool isExiste = Directory.Exists(pathstring);

                        if (!isExiste)
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathstring);
                        }

                        string uploadpath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathstring, filename1);

                        oTipoRecurso = new TipoRecursoDTO() { cNombre = cNombre, cClave = cClave, cHashtag = cHashtag, cColor = cColor, cRutaImagen = "img/TipoRecursos/" + filename1 };

                        file.SaveAs(uploadpath);
                    }
                }

                TipoRecursoDTO imagenes = oTipoRecurso;

                oTipoRecurso = AgregarTipoRecurso.Agregar(oTipoRecurso);

                cEstatus = "Ok";
                cMensaje = "El tipo de recurso se ha guardado correctamente.";
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                cEstatus = "Error";
                cMensaje = Ex.Message;
            }

            return Json(new { Estatus = cEstatus, Mensaje = cMensaje }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Aqui mi logica de negocio:
  public static TipoRecursoDTO Agregar(TipoRecursoDTO _oTipoRecurso)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SIRHEntities ctx = new SIRHEntities())
                {
                    UnidadDeTrabajo<tblCat_TipoRecurso> TipoRecursoValidate = new UnidadDeTrabajo<tblCat_TipoRecurso>();

                    ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                    ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    ctx.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                    Expression<Func<tblCat_TipoRecurso, bool>> lCondicion = a => a.cNombre == _oTipoRecurso.cNombre;

                    TipoRecursoValidate.Repositorio.Validacion(lCondicion, "tipos de recurso", "nombre");

                    tblCat_TipoRecurso oTipoRecurso = new tblCat_TipoRecurso();


                    oTipoRecurso.cNombre = _oTipoRecurso.cNombre;
                    oTipoRecurso.cClave = _oTipoRecurso.cClave;
                    oTipoRecurso.cHashtag = _oTipoRecurso.cHashtag;
                    oTipoRecurso.cColor = _oTipoRecurso.cColor;
                    oTipoRecurso.cRutaImagen = _oTipoRecurso.cRutaImagen;
                    oTipoRecurso.lEstatus = true;
                    oTipoRecurso.dtFechaAlta = DateTime.Now;

                    ctx.tblCat_TipoRecurso.Add(oTipoRecurso);

                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                    return new TipoRecursoDTO(oTipoRecurso);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Nota: se guarda correctamente, pero ahora lo que quiere es recuperar esa imagen en la vista por si el usuario desea cambiarla por otra. en mi base de datos el tipo de dato es un varchar.

aqui mi vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias guardar solo el nombre de la imagen en tu base de datos.

Ahora suponiendo que le envías a la vista un model:

```
@model MiProyecto.Models.TuClaseModelo
```

Luego en una etiqueta img puedes concatenar el directorio mas el nombre de la imagen (varchar de tu base de datos)

```
 <img src="~/Assets/img/TipoRecursos/@Model.Imagen">
```

Comment: no utilizo un model para la vista, mi vista es con html

Comment: Asi retorno los valores, sin utilizar en model:  <input type="hidden" id="iIdTipoRecurso" value="@ViewBag.oTipoRecurso.iIdTipoRecurso" />

Comment: Entonces es el mismo procedimiento pero en lugar de model hazlo con tu ViewBag  <img src="~/Assets/img/TipoRecursos/@ViewBag.oTipoRecurso.Imagen">